# How can I get 2D Matrices from a 3D matrix?

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, 3d, 2d

I have looked for someone with my same question but I haven't found nothing so specific.

I have a 3D matrix **( m x n x z )** and I want to get from that Matrix, the 2D matrices **m x z** and **n x z**. I am working with 3D medical images and I need different views of my patient; I haven´t any problem to get the m x n matrix with this code:

```
 for z=1:length(z)
 figure;
 imshow (A (:,:,z))
 end
```

but if I do the same with the other variables, my resultant matrix is still a 3D matrix and I can't show it with the "imshow" function.

Please, could you help me?

Thank you so much.

Comment: `z = 1:length(z)` is certainly not a great loop variable name.

Comment: Use `squeeze` to remove singleton dimensions. Example: `imshow(squeeze(A (:,n,:)))`

Comment: @LuisMendo That should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`squeeze`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) to remove singleton dimensions. Example:

```
k = 1; %// or any desired value from 1 to n
imshow(squeeze(A(:,k,:)))
```

*How this works*: `A(:,k,:)` has size `m`x`1`x`z` (3D array). `squeeze` removes that singleton dimension, so that `squeeze(A(:,k,:))` has size `m`x`z` (2D array).